# Is there a Lift cheatsheet / quickref?

Tags: scala, frameworks, lift

I found a couple of blogs on how to get started with Lift, but I need a quick reference. Something like: here you define the application map, this is how to write snippets, etc.
I want to start a Lift app that is not "hello world" and I need the tl;dr version :)

Comment: At some point, though, you may want to r one of the tl versions, so you're not sol when something goes fubar on your site.

Comment: Some books here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe : http://wiki.liftweb.net/index.php/Cheat_Sheet